# Как передать несколько ролей в JWT токен?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Разбирал пример для входа по JWT токену https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php

В нем как бы можно быть либо администратором либо пользователем. А если у меня в приложении несколько ролей и можно быть одновременно и менеджером и эйчаром одновременно.

Будет ли правильно если я просто продублируют роли из базы:

```
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, person.Login),
                new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role[0])
                new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role[1])
                new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role[2])
            };
```

Или это неправильно? Очень смущает что автокомплит подсказывает что у ClaimsIdentity могут быть только два варианта (или DefaultNameClaimType или DefaultRoleClaimType) и нет просто RoleClaimType

Это же роль по умолчанию, основаная типа. А как задать просто роль? Сразу несколько обычных ролей?

Полазил по гитхабу, видел что зачем-то фамилию заносят как роль, это верно? https://github.com/mvSapphire/hierarchy-tree/blob/698b8ec3246269d1868c21e52d29f64e195b07b0/SoftServeTestTask/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L93

А вот тут опять только одну роль можно и опять непонятно как правильно https://github.com/matryosha/Sengis/blob/8ce10b70f40853a6c2700371ff5f303e916e08d6/Sengis.WebApi/Infrastructure/ClaimsManager.cs#L11

Подскажите пожалуста а то я себя окончательно запутал

Comment: А зачем вам вообще эти Claims нужны? Если для проверки ролей в `[Authorize(Roles="Manager,HR")` то там вроде как Claims не нужны. А так ничто не мешает указать `new Claim(ClaimTypes.фыва, role[0])` - там их десятки. Есть и ClaimTypes.Role - годится?

Comment: Да для авторизации. Хочу проект без таблиц Identity но у меня тоже есть таблица ролей и таблица пользователей. я читаю пользователя и его роли, роли записываю в claims чтобы потом проверить в атрибуте авторизации. ClaimTypes выглядит похоже, но не знаю подойдет ли и как правильно. А где можно об этом почитать как правильно подскажете

Comment: Это нормально, можно даже не использовать enum для названия, Identity подхватит и просто "role": `new Claim("role", "admin"), new Claim("role", "super admin")`